# Save a html file in .msg format or disable the send button of outloook msg

Tags: html, angular, email, angular6, html-email

I have requirement to save a html file as .msg format so that it can be sent later. The html of type of mock of normal mail with only basic features (from, to, cc, subject, body). Not sure how it can be achieved.

Other way is disable the send button of new outlook email so that it can be sent later. I do not think that this can be achieved.

Any clue would be great help, stuck with this since a long time.

I read in some websites that there a specific format for this but it not get any template or example for it.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right avenue, web-based Outlook add-ins don't allow disabling the send button. Also, there are no methods for creating items based on a template. You can simply set properties separately based on the data you have.

You may consider developing a COM-based (for example, VSTO based) add-in instead where you can create items [based on the template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.createitemfromtemplate) and do the required UI modifications. See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2019) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the info, it really helped :-)